# How to use \usepackage{pst-barcode}

Tags: color, pstricks, pst-barcode

When using `\usepackage {pst-barcode}`  I get error :

```
  \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,x11names]{pstricks}% Options for xcolor
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(3.5,1.2in)
\psbarcode[linecolor=red]{1613198400316}{includetext inkspread=0.1}{ean13}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your edited example works just fine with `xelatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

Comment: The last digit "6" is wrong, it must be "7". See my example

Comment: @Herbert And if I use the digit " 6" how can I make it work ? i need bar code with the tex 1613198400316

Comment: The 13th digit is a check digit for ean13 and is computed depending to the Otter digits See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number_(EAN)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass the options for `xcolor` via `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,x11names]{pstricks}% Options for xcolor
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(3.5,1.2in)
\psbarcode[linecolor=red]{1234567}{includetext inkspread=0.5}{ean8}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

`xcolor` itself loads by default `color`

And with

```
\psbarcode[linecolor=red]{1613198400317}{includetext inkspread=0.5}{ean13}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for you answer, but when i tried your code to ean13, not function to me

Comment: Did you run the example with xelatex?

Comment: i run with latex->dvips->ps2pdf . But when I try your code with 1613198400316 , bar codes without appears , that happen?

Comment: My Code was ean8, but your Long Numbers needs ean13

Comment: i used ean13 but when i change 1613198400317 for 1613198400316 the barcode is not appers. Texmaker showme the error , see image. ...

Comment: The number must be `{161319840031}` or `{1613198400317}` . In the first case the control digit is computed internally and in the second case it is corect with `7` but not a `6` as in your above example.

Answer (score 1):

`Pstricks` (loaded by `pst-barcode`)  already loads `xcolor` without option. If you load the latter with an option, there will be an ‘option clash’. The solution consists in loading the option from within the document class, which will  propose it to all subsequent packages, until one of them recognises it.

Alternative solution: write in the preamble `\PassOptionsToPackage{selected options}{xcolor}`.